# Handing requests off to other intents

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a dialogflow agent with 3 intents:

- Default Welcome Intent
- Default Fallback Intent
- My Intent

My intent has a firebase web hook for fulfillment.  When I enter a conversation with my chatbot, I get `Default Welcome Intent`.  But as soon, as I ask a question that is handled by `My Intent` I seem stuck in `My Intent` even if i say something like `hello` after that.  How do I exit out of my fulfillment and clear the state so that the Default Fallback and Default Welcome start working again?  A lot of the fulfillment samples I've seen, handle these other intents within the custom fulfillment which seems wrong when you have these defaults already configured.  Another example, is I enabled `SmallTalk` and after asking a question that's filled by `My Intent`, I then ask 'how old are you', this intent fires the agent.smalltalk.age against `My Intent` which makes no sense really.

Fulfillment code:

```
var https = require ('https');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const DialogFlowApp = require('actions-on-google').DialogFlowApp;
const WELCOME_INTENT= 'Default Welcome Intent';
const FALLBACK_INTENT = 'Default Fallback Intent';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  let action = request.body.queryResult.action;
  response.setHeader('Content-Type','applicaiton/json');
  const parameters = request.body.queryResult.parameters;

  console.log("action: " + action)
  if (action === 'input.wifi'){
    getClientCount(parameters['geo-city'], response);
  }
});

function getClientCount(location, CloudFnResponse) {
          var chat = "sample text";
          CloudFnResponse.send(buildChatResponse(chat));
          return;
        });
});

}

function buildChatResponse(chat) {
    return JSON.stringify({"fulfillmentText": chat});
}
```

Default Fallback Intent:
[image]

Default Welcome Intent:
[image]

My Intent:
[image]

In the last screenshot please ignore the 'end of conversation' checkbox I was trying it out to see how it changed the behavior when I was taking the screenshot.

Comment: Can you update your question to show a screen shot of the "My Intent" Intent? (I assume the default intents are configured as they were out of the box, but show those too, if not.) What inputs are you trying that you are expecting to trigger the fallback intent?

Comment: added the 3 intent screenshots. For inputs I'll ask it how many wifi connections there are at a location for example then after it answers i'll just say 'thanks' and it fires an action against the My Intent rather than the default.

Comment: What happens if you turn smalltalk off? How are you testing the responses?

Comment: And if you do say "hello", how does it reply? And how can you tell that it is the "My Intent" intent that is handling it?

Comment: Turning off smalltalk solved the issue.  I don't really understand why.  I was testing responses with the Google Assist tester in Dialogflow.

Comment: If i said 'hello' with it turned on,  i'd end up with a MalformedResponse because the action wasn't matching within my Fulfillment handler and so it'd just bomb out there.  I was cosole.logging the action in the Fulfillment handler and thats how I could tell 'My Intent' was the handler.

Comment: And with smalltalk turned off, "hello" uses the Fallback Intent? Ok. So at this point, you're mostly looking for understanding of why smalltalk messes with things like that?

Comment: Yeah, admittedly smalltalk wasn't actually working yet, even though I'd enabled it and filled in some answers.  When I imported the smalltalk prebuilt into a separate agent, it obviously looked pretty different, then just clicking over the toggle in an existing project.

Comment: To be clear - you imported the Prebuilt Smalltalk agent? Or Turned it on using the Smalltalk left navigation?

Comment: In this agent, i used the left navigation.  After it I saw it was not working, I created a second agent and imported the prebuilt to see how it was set up differently.

Comment: Just to follow up one more time, exporting all the Smalltalk intents from the prebuilt agent and importing them into my Agent gets smalltalk working for me, albeit without the niceties of the left panel UI but this works well enough for me.

Comment: It is good to hear that you found a solution for your question and it worked for you. For future reference, would you mind posting your solution as an answer to your question? So anyone can easily find it if they have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off smalltalk solved the issue and exporting all the Smalltalk intents from the prebuilt agent and importing them into my Agent got smalltalk working.